# I have already specified different table names to avoid ambiguity still error exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
With tbl_name as 
     (Select top(1000) * 
      from tblEmployee as E right join tblTransaction as T
      on E.EmployeeNumber = T.EmployeeNumber
      where E.EmployeeNumber is null
      order by T.EmployeeNumber)
Select Distinct(T.EmployeeNumber) as EmployeeNum from tbl_name
```

The error which I am getting:-

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 24 The column 'EmployeeNumber' was
> specified multiple times for 'tbl_name'.

Comment: This is why you don't use `*`, *define* your columns in the `SELECT`. Clearly both your tables, `tblEmployee` and `tblTransaction` have the column `EmployeeNumber` and your `SELECT *` states you want **both** of them.

Comment: You JOIN two tables both having `EmployeeNumber` columns and then return both of them... this is the mistake

Comment: Also `Distinct(T.EmployeeNumber)` is a little odd syntax. `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it's an operator. It's applied to the *entire* data set. Putting the column listed after `DISTINCT` in parentheses makes it look like you think `DISTINCT` does something else.

Comment: @Marco In the select statement I have specified T.EmployeeNumber to remove ambiguity and when you run the query specified under the 'With" statement it gives me the desired result. Where is the compiler getting confused in this scenario?

Comment: @Larnu Got the distinct part but still confused with the query.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you have the same column in both the tables you have in the Join. instead of `SELECT TOP(1000) *` specify the column names from the proper table. if 2 tables are having the same column name and you need both of them in the result set, please give one of the columns a different alias name. something like this

```
WITH tbl_name
     AS (SELECT TOP (1000) 
            E_EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber ,
            T_EmployeeNumber = T.EmployeeNumber
         FROM tblEmployee AS E
              RIGHT JOIN tblTransaction AS T ON E.EmployeeNumber = T.EmployeeNumber
         WHERE E.EmployeeNumber IS NULL
         ORDER BY T.EmployeeNumber)
     SELECT DISTINCT
            (T_EmployeeNumber) AS EmployeeNum
     FROM tbl_name;
```

Also, Looking at the query, the below will also work better than your current query

```
SELECT
        *
        FROM tblEmployee E
            WHERE EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1 FROM tblTransaction T WHERE EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber
            )
```

this will give the same result with a better performace

Answer (score 4):

It is entirely unclear how an employee number in `tblTransaction` would not exist.  If you had properly declared foreign key relationships, this could not happen.

You *can* use the structure of your query, but I would recommend `LEFT JOIN`:

```
with tbl_name as (
      select top (1000) T.EmployeeNumber
      from tblTransaction T left join
           tblEmployee E
           on E.EmployeeNumber = T.EmployeeNumber
      where E.EmployeeNumber is null
      order by T.EmployeeNumber
     )
Select Distinct EmployeeNumber
from tbl_name;
```

Your query has several issues:

- The `select *` is doing *exactly* what the error message suggests.  There are multiple columns with the same name.
- The `T` in the outer query's reference to `T.EmployeeNumber` is not defined.
- You are using parentheses around `DISTINCT`, as if it were a function.  It is not.  There is a syntactic element in SQL that is `SELECT DISTINCT`.

I'm not sure if you really need the `TOP`.  `NOT EXISTS` is a more natural way to write the query:

```
select distinct t.EmployeeNumber
from tblTransaction T 
where not exists (select 1
                  from tblEmployee E
                  where E.EmployeeNumber = T.EmployeeNumber
                 );
```